# Find databasetype ( SQlite, Mysql, PostgreSQL ) from dbapi in python

Tags: python, database, python-db-api

I need to find out what kind of database I am working against based on data from an dbapi cursor instance. Have not found any clues on how to do this in the dbapi docs. Can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't part of the dbapi 2.0, at least to my knowledge.  However, you can implement a function to obtain the module name from a given database object (cursor, connection) and map that to a well-known string for your application to use:

```
_DBNAME_MAP = {
    'psycopg2': 'postgres',
    'MySQLdb': 'mysql',
    'sqlite3': 'sqlite',
    'sqlite': 'sqlite'
    }

def get_dbname(dbobj):
    mod = dbobj.__class__.__module__.split('.', 1)[0]
    return _DBNAME_MAP.get(mod)
```

Examples:

```
>>> s_conn = sqlite3.connect('foo.db')
>>> get_dbname(s_conn)
'sqlite'
>>> get_dbname(s_conn.cursor())
'sqlite'

>>> p_conn = psycopg2.connect('host=localhost user=postgres')
>>> get_dbname(p_conn)
'postgres'
>>> get_dbname(p_conn.cursor())
'postgres'
```